# Performing multiple Network Operations in a Service

Tags: android

quick question, Whats the best way to perform multiple network operations on a service. Consider something like a weather service where one has to update periodically. for each time, i call in this order

```
   getCurrentWeather();
      getForecast();
      getForecasthours()
```

which makes a Http request and obtains data in JSON. This returns a new JSON Object for each method which is used to update the UI.  Now sometimes, we are not sure how long one of this operations might take, so is using multiple AsyncTasks in a Service a better way to go about this? or is this sufficient enough or are there other better ways to do this. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Async task is a good way. But there are more frameworks that have more features for making json http requests.

Have a look at Google Volley framework.

https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley